# django handle newlines in textarea

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

```
  <textarea id="my" ></textarea>

  p=post(body=value)
  p.save()
```

Here I am trying to save the content of the textarea to database but i see that new lines are converted to spaces and then saved.How to handle this on the server side..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They're almost certainly not being converted to new-lines, the problem is likely to be the way you're displaying them.

Try displaying them in your template using the [`linebreaks`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?#linebreaks) filter, like this:

```
{{ mypost.body|linebreaks }}
```

Comment: @Rajeev - what do you mean ignored? In your template? It's a bit hard to know what you're trying to accomplish. Could you post the output (i.e. HTML source) that you're getting, and what you want to get?

Comment: I believe he's talking about the saving process, not the display side of things.